# not able to create the rule for the ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

What am I going wrong in the below query?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

The error I am getting:

```
error validating "ingress.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend, ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with
--validate=false
```

Comment: Hi Subhajit Das welcome to SO. It is, as the explicit error says, a schema validation failure. You are trying to use [the old `v1beta1` Ingress](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#ingressbackend-v1beta1-extensions) `apiVersion:` structure with [the new `v1` Ingress `apiVersion`](https://v1-19.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#ingressbackend-v1-networking-k8s-io)

Comment: Did suggested solution help you?

Answer (score 1):

Ingress spec has changed since updated to v1. Try:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) you need to change ServiceName and ServicePort.

> Each HTTP rule contains (...) a list of paths (for example,  `/testpath`), each of which has an associated backend defined with a  `service.name`  and a  `service.port.name`  or  `service.port.number`. Both the host and path must match the content of an incoming request before the load balancer directs traffic to the referenced Service.

Here is your yaml file with corrections:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

ServiceName and ServicePort no keywords are available like that in v1 .

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /nginx
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

service name and service port syntax is incorrect. Follow the below sample

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx-example
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: nginx-ingress
annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
rules:

- http:
  paths:

  - path: /nginx
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
    service:
    name: nginx
    port:
    number: 80